# Magento only load products that assign to both categories

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, category-products

I am going to modify default magento category filter.

I have two categories **Fruits** and **Apple**. In fruits there are **100 products** and in Apple there are **50 products**.

`www.demo.com/fruits.html` (category page) this is listing all 100 products.

But now when i click on Apple from left category filter, it should load only 50 products that are assign to both category.

`www.demo.com/fruuits.html?cat=10` (10 is Apple category id)

I am not getting how and where to modify code to get the result as per my need.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to load product collection by category id

```
$category_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cat'); // 10 as Category Id
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) 
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->setOrder('price', 'ASC');
```